# Repeating an equation including its content and number

Tags: macros, equations

I would like to re-use equations with the same content and number. I know that the `thmtools` package has a `restatable` environment to do this for environments (like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51288/69445)), but I would also like to do this with a single equation that is only part of some environment.

I had a look at the following questions which only aim at repeating the equation number but typing the whole equation twice (the first three) or repeat the content of the equation without a number (the last one):

- [repeating an equation and getting the same equation number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67651/repeating-an-equation-and-getting-the-same-equation-number)
- [Using the same number for repeated use of the same equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33750/using-the-same-number-for-repeated-use-of-the-same-equation)
- [Repeat a previously labelled equation without changing the label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124821/repeat-a-previously-labelled-equation-without-changing-the-label)
- [How to use macros to repeat math equations in different settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254173/how-to-use-macros-to-repeat-math-equations-in-different-settings)

Based on the answers provided there and on the [last part of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283059/69445) I tried to create a macro `\restatableeq` for restable equations like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\restatableeq}[3]{\label{#3}#2\xdef#1{\unexpanded#2\unexpanded\tag{\unexpanded\ref{#3}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
\restatableeq{\eqone}{This & is & eqation 1}{eq1}\\
Another & simple & equation
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
One & more & equation\\
\restatableeq{\eqtwo}{This & is & eqation 2}{eq2}
\end{eqnarray}

Here, we use (\ref{eq1}) and (\ref{eq2}) again:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\eqone\\
\eqtwo
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and yields:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   T
l.10 ...ableeq{\eqone}{This & is & eqation 1}{eq1}
                                                  \\
?
```

My guess is that the `&` symbols are not treated as intended but I may well be wrong there.

How can I define a command like `\restatableeq` that allows me to re-use equations with the same content and number in a setting like in this example (and give it a label such that I can still use `\ref` as usual in addition to that)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of flaws in your document.

1. You use `\xdef{\unexpanded...}`.  This is essentially `\gdef`, which totally suffices here.
2. Your use of `\unexpanded` is wrong.  `\unexpanded` expects a balanced token list delimited by explicit `{`, `}`.  If you want to protect a single token from expansion in `\edef`, use `\noexpand`.  Enrico wrote a [nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158906/10995) about that.
3. You use `eqnarray`.  [Never use `eqnarray`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/10995)
4. `\tag` does not work in `eqnarray`.

Here is a fixed version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\restatableeq}[3]{\label{#3}#2\gdef#1{#2\tag{\ref{#3}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\restatableeq{\eqone}{This & is & eqation 1}{eq1}\\
Another & simple & equation
\end{align}

\begin{align}
One & more & equation\\
\restatableeq{\eqtwo}{This & is & eqation 2}{eq2}
\end{align}

Here, we use (\ref{eq1}) and (\ref{eq2}) again:
\begin{align*}
\eqone\\
\eqtwo
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]