# Using equation numbers as part of examples

Tags: equations

I want to use equations that I have already numbered as part of an example. i.e. above the example I define an equation for potential energy (3.2), then showing students how to use it in an example I want to write out the equation again and use the same number.

Potential energy is given by
E=mgh (3.2)

Example:
find the potential energy gained of a 30 kg child that climbs 10 m of stairs.
E=mgh (3.2)

Can this be done?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285044/15925 or one of the questions it links to help?

Comment: Yes thank you, using the tag code sorted it.

Comment: Yes thank you, appreciate the support